# example fails with undefined method `model_name' for RSpec::Mocks::Mock:Class and Failure/Error: Bookmark.should_receive(:new)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rspec, devise

Hello I don't know why these test fails. That are example from a "expert" german book
Maybe someone can help me....
https://github.com/AGERECKE/Rails-Book-Project
http://pastebin.com/q4kS59ek

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. about `received: 0 times with any arguments`
   You use method [`visit`](https://github.com/AGERECKE/Rails-Book-Project/blob/07b0fdceb9b28a3ef065d37c5dad7eb587e6f03f/spec/bookmarks_controller2_spec.rb#L71) which usually is used for "acceptance" tests not for controller tests. I don't know what this method does in this case. I think you should change it on `post`
2. about `undefined method 'model_name' for RSpec::Mocks::Mock:Class`
   You stub `Bookmark.stub(:new).and_return(@bookmark)` where `@bookmark = double(Bookmark)` - it means that `@bookmark` is NOT instance of `Bookmark`, it is instance of `RSpec::Mocks::Mock:Class`.
   When action `create` starts to work it tries to save record. Method `save` returns false (it is stubbed by you) and a view `new` is rendered again. This page contains form based on `@bookmark` which calls `model_name`.
   Possible solution: use `@bookmark = Bookmark.new`

Comment: Hi @gotva, i changed `visit` to `post` and in bookmarkscontroller i've changed  new method  `@bookmark = Bookmark.new(params[:bookmark]) to @bookmark = Bookmark.new` but i get [link](http://pastebin.com/zV8RbfRi). maybe i miss understood you.

Comment: you controller was correct (I hope). The problem is with this [stub](https://github.com/AGERECKE/Rails-Book-Project/blob/master/spec/bookmarks_controller2_spec.rb#L18). For exactly this [describe](https://github.com/AGERECKE/Rails-Book-Project/blob/master/spec/bookmarks_controller2_spec.rb#L18) you should change `@bookmark = double(Bookmark)` on `@bookmark = Bookmark.new`